# How do I create x seconds video preview automatically for Vimeo-videos

Tags: video, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

We have a website that show our own PRO vimeo videos behind paid login. Now we want to list all videos on open website but only show x seconds of preview of every video. When not logged in user is clicking on the video, there should only be x seconds of preview and after x seconds I would prefer to be able to add a graphic purchase message. Example "Become a member if you want to have access to whole video."

Answer (score 1):

Sure is! I actually just implemented this the other day. It utilizes the froogaloop library Vimeo provides. Please read more on it here: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

Here is an example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pL5cj1yu/1/

Below is the code in the fiddle for posterity. The code snippet below should work right out of the box on a valid HTML page. **Keep in mind Vimeo reports the time in seconds ONLY.**

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
    <iframe id="player1" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?api=1&player_id=player1" width="630" height="354" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <div>
    <p>Status: <span class="status"></span></p>
    </div>



    <script>
    $(function() {
var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);
var status = $('.status');

// When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
setTimeout(function () {
player.addEvent('ready', function() {
status.text('ready');

player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
});
});
// Call the API when a button is pressed
//$('button').bind('click', function() {
//   player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
//});

function onPause(id) {
    //when paused show alert
    alert(id);
}

function onFinish(id) {

}

function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
status.text(data.seconds);
//set time var
var Time = data.seconds;
//if time is 10 seconds pause. 
    if (Time >= '10') {
        player.api('pause');

    }
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Vid.Watch](https://vid.watch) - I think it's what your'e looking for. Vid.Watch is an automated SaaS platform that automatically generates video previews for websites. These previews are automatically displayed on the website (on mouseover or autoplay on video thumbnail) and can be customized with editorial control. (disclaimer: I work at Vid.Watch :))

Comment: This business doesn't seem to exist anymore.